# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}{1 + \cos^2\theta}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}{1 + \cos^2\theta}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

My attempt :I tried to use the beta function, but I couldn't.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Any particular substitutions, for instance?

Comment: I try $\cos \theta = \tan u$.

Comment: I try too $\cos \theta = 1 - u^4$.

Comment: @Mathsource The first substitution is a good one. What did you get after that? (or why did you stop?).

Comment: Currently this question is without any context. It would be great if you could show us your attempt based on the substitution you mention and tell us where you are stuck with that.

Answer (score 6):

with $\cos\theta = \tan \frac t2$

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}{1 + \cos^2\theta}d\theta =\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\tan t}\>dt\overset{x^2=\cot t}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^4}dx
= \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this identity for ${}_{2}F_{1}$ helps:

$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sqrt{\cos\theta}}{1+\cos^2 \theta}d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}\theta d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}$

Now using

$\displaystyle (x)_{n} = \frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ and $(1)_{n}=n!$

where $(x)_{n}$ is the rising factorial

$\displaystyle I = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}=  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{n}} =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1)_{n}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{n}}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{}_{2}F_{1}\left(1,\frac{3}{4};\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$

With this identity:

$ \displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;a-b+1;-1) = \frac{\Gamma(a-b+1)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}a+1\right)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}a-b+1\right)}$

we have

$\displaystyle I= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2} =\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

In search of a simple solution and after many attempts, I found this solution. Let $\cos \theta = \tan \alpha$ and $d\theta = -\dfrac{\sec^2 \alpha \ d\alpha}{\sqrt{1 - \tan \alpha}}$. Thus,
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}{1 + \cos^2 \theta}d\theta = \int_{\pi/4}^{0}\dfrac{\sqrt{\tan \alpha}(-\sec^2 \alpha)d\alpha}{(1 + \tan^2 \alpha)\sqrt{1 - \tan^2 \alpha}} = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\dfrac{\tan \alpha}{1 - \tan^2 \alpha}}d\alpha \quad \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
I = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin(2\alpha)}{\cos(2\alpha)}}d\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{1/2}\alpha \cos^{-1/2}\alpha d\alpha \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
I = \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}B(1/4,3/4)= \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/4)} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}
$$

Comment: Nice answer.(+1)

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)}}{1+\cos^{2}(\theta)}d\theta=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\cos^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}(\theta)d\theta$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}(\theta)d\theta$$

by [Fubini/Tonelli theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). Then using the trigonometric representation of the Beta function

$$\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(\frac{1+n}{2},\frac{1+m}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}(x)\sin^{m}(x)dx,\space \text{for}\space n,m>-1$$

we obtain $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}(\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(n+\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$

and the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)}}{1+\cos^{2}(\theta)}d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(\frac{5\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{9}{4}; -1\right)\, }{3\, \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}-\frac{4\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{4}\right)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{7}{4},2;\frac{13}{4}; -1\right)\, }{7\, \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{4}\right)}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

where $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).